# Why CloudBlockBlob.Startcopyblob copies only 0bytes?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-media-services

Sometimes I have a case that,copying from one blob to input assets blob copies only 0bytes...
I am retrying after the first try and also delay it for 80sec, but nothing changes...
The file is video and its size is 340mb... If you guys need any information, I can reply it...

```
 private async Task CreateInputAssetBlobAsync(UploadRequest request)
        {
            var cloudBlobContainer = new CloudBlobContainer(request.InputAssetStorageUri);
            var blockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(request.BlobName);

            var storageCredentials = new Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials(_apiAccess.TempBlobAccountName, _apiAccess.TempBlobContainerKey);
            var tempBlobContainer = new CloudBlobContainer(new Uri(_apiAccess.TempBlobContainerAddress), storageCredentials);
            var tempBlockBlob = tempBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(request.BlobName);

            try
            {
                await blockBlob.StartCopyAsync(tempBlockBlob);
                
                do
                {
                    if (blockBlob.CopyState.Status == CopyStatus.Pending)
                        await Task.Delay(1000);
                    await blockBlob.FetchAttributesAsync();
                }
                while (blockBlob.CopyState.Status != CopyStatus.Success);

                await blockBlob.FetchAttributesAsync();
                if (blockBlob.Properties.Length <= 0)
                {
                    Task.Delay(80000);

                    await blockBlob.StartCopyAsync(tempBlockBlob);
                   
                    do
                    {
                        if (blockBlob.CopyState.Status == CopyStatus.Pending)
                            await Task.Delay(1000);
                        await blockBlob.FetchAttributesAsync();
                    }
                    while (blockBlob.CopyState.Status != CopyStatus.Success);
                }
               
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is `blockBlob` the intended source, or the intended destination?

Comment: what do you mean? (container is created by asset)...

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the Remarks section of the Azure Blob API here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/copy-blob

There are several remarks to be aware of with StartCopy blob.

- “The Blob service copies blobs on a best-effort basis."
- “For a block blob or an append blob, the Blob service creates a committed blob of zero length before returning from this operation."
- “For all blob types, you can call Get Blob or Get Blob Properties on the destination blob to check the status of the copy operation. The final blob will be committed when the copy completes."

If the copies in your storage account are never completing, I would advise opening a support ticket with the details on the storage account, time and operation ids, etc.

Hope that is somewhat helpful.

Comment: Copying is completing and successing but it is still 0bytes

Answer (score 0):

Note: you should not use

```
do
{
    if (blockBlob.CopyState.Status == CopyStatus.Pending)
       await Task.Delay(1000);
    await blockBlob.FetchAttributesAsync();
 }
 while (blockBlob.CopyState.Status != CopyStatus.Success);
```

but

```
do
{
   await Task.Delay(1000);
   await blockBlob.FetchAttributesAsync();
}
while (blockBlob.CopyState.Status == CopyStatus.Pending);
```

otherwise you will get an infinite loop if the copy has an error.
May be this is what happening in your case ?

Comment: Do you have any suggestions about 0Byte blob?

Comment: The error comes from the destination container. It's not the destination but the source.
`var cloudBlobContainer = new CloudBlobContainer(request.InputAssetStorageUri);
            var blockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(request.BlobName);`
It should be
`CloudBlobContainer destContainer = new CloudBlobContainer(destSasUri);
            var blockBlob = destContainer .GetBlockBlobReference(request.BlobName);`

Comment: var cloudBlobContainer = new CloudBlobContainer(request.InputAssetStorageUri);
            var blockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(request.BlobName);

Comment: I didn't get what you mean

Comment: You use the source container, but you should specify another container for the destination

Comment: I am using container in where i want to copy tempblockblob

Comment: await blockBlob.StartCopyAsync(tempBlockBlob); see i am copyng from source blob to destinationblob

Comment: Try
`await tempBlockBlob.StartCopyAsync(blockBlob);`

Comment: i will try it rn

Comment: In my code that works, I see that I get a new CloudBlockBlob object once the copy is launched.
Try something like this :
`await tempBlockBlob.StartCopyAsync(blockBlob);
tempBlockBlob = (CloudBlockBlob)await tempBlobContainer.GetBlobReferenceFromServerAsync(request.BlobName);`
and then do the fectattribute and tests with tempBlockBlob

Comment: I think my previous comment is a good path. I got a 0 byte blob if I don't add the second line.

Answer (score 0):

In my code that works, I see that I retrieve a new CloudBlockBlob object once the copy is launched. Add the second line :

```
await tempBlockBlob.StartCopyAsync(blockBlob);
tempBlockBlob = (CloudBlockBlob)await tempBlobContainer.GetBlobReferenceFromServerAsync(request.BlobName);
```

and then do the fetchattribute and checks with tempBlockBlob. I got a 0 byte blob if I don't add the second line.